# Forward declare classes, class redefinition

Tags: c++, header, forward-declaration

So i have 2 classes let's call it class A and B which inside of those classes have a reference for each other as a function's arguments. When i try to forward declare it like this:

```
// A.h (Header guarded)
namespace ns {
    class B { // Attempt to forward declare B
    public:
        int getRand();
    };

    class A {
    public:
        float a, b;

        void aFunc(B &b);       
    };
}
```

---

```
// B.h (Header guarded)
namespace ns {
    class A { // Attempt to forward declare A
    public:
        float a, b;
    };

    class B {
    public:
        void bFunc(A &a);
        int getRand();
    };
}
```

---

The thing is, when i do this i got `'class' type redefinition` error. I've been searching for the solution and still haven't came to a solution. Am i doing this right? Which i suppose i'm not, can you tell me where did i do wrong here?

Comment: That's not a forward declaration you got there! `class B;` would be.

Comment: @jrok hmm, but what if i need to access B's variables from A? Without it it would generate an error which is `incomplete type is not allowed`

Comment: That depends on the classes. Tell us more about them and what do you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not forward declaration, they're definition definitely.

You should

```
// A.h (Header guarded)
namespace ns {
    class B; // forward declare B

    class A {
    public:
        // Some functions with B references as arguments        
    };
}
```

And it's same for `B.h`.

According to your situation, there're just some member functions which take forward declared class as parameters, you can leave the declaration of member functions in .h file, and provide their definition in .cpp file. Such as

```
// A.h (Header guarded)
namespace ns {
    class B; // forward declare B
    class A {
    public:
        float a, b;
        void aFunc(B &b);       
    };
}

// B.h (Header guarded)
namespace ns {
    class A; // forward declare A
    class B {
    public:
        void bFunc(A &a);
        int getRand();
    };
}

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
namespace ns {
    void A::aFunc(B& b) { /* ... */ }
}

// B.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
namespace ns {
    void B::bFunc(A& b) { /* ... */ }
    int B::getRand() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Wwhat if i need to access B's variables from A? Without it it would generate an error which is `incomplete type is not allowed`.

Comment: @Greffin28 - Please re-read up about object oriented design and encapsulation

Comment: @Greffin28 If there're just some member functions which take forward declared class as parameters, you can just leave the declaration of member functions in .h file, and provide their definition in .cpp file.

Comment: @Greffin28 You provide separate implementation outside the structural declaration. I.e., don't provide A::method bodies in-class-declaration; get Java out of your head. Do it after at least the formal declaration of `B` (and `A`) is complete.

Comment: @songyuanyao I did it like that because some site really does teach it like that. *sigh*. Anyway, i tried to implement your code and it's working fine now! Whoa, never thought about including both headers on the cpp. Thank you very much for the help, i appreciate it.